# Linear operator that transforms positive-definite matrix into another positive-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

What can be said about this operator? I'm suspecting it must be positive definite, can someone see an elegant way to show this?

**Edit**
This is more rigorously stated without proof in Example 2.2.1(ii) of Bhatia's Positive Definite Matrices [book](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Elessa/tesis/Positive%20Definite%20Matrices.pdf)
(he uses positive to mean "positive semidefinite")

[image]

Comment: By positive definite, do you include that it is symmetric? If not, the skew-symmetric part can be modified without changing pd.

Comment: And by "transforms", do you allow conjugation or other actions?

Comment: Yes, I meant symmetric (it's included in definition of PD, no?) Also, by transforms, I mean regular linear operation - operator can be viewed as a matrix T such that vec(y)=T.vec(x), where x and y are PD matrices

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Unfortunately, whether PD entails positive definite depends on the context. For some, a real matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A + A^T$ is "symmetric positive definite".

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Regarding your edit: the result is specific to maps from positive definite matrices to $\Bbb C$

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to prove something for T that maps between full-rank covariance matrices, is that sufficient to guarantee complete positivity of T or I need something else?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You would need something else. For example, the transpose map is not completely positive

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I think you should open a new question that explains the specifics of your map and why it would be helpful to show that the map is itself positive semidefinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things a bit more concrete: the map under consideration is a linear map $\Phi: \Bbb C^{n \times n} \to \Bbb C^{m \times m}$. I believe that you mean to say that we are considering any such $\Phi$ with the property that $\Phi(A)$ is positive semidefinite whenever $A$ is positive semidefinite; such an operator is called a [positive map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map#Definition).

It is not implicitly clear what it should mean that $\Phi$ is "positive definite" in and of itself. However, there is an interesting result that considers something like this, namely [Choi's theorem on completely positive maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps). We define the "Choi matrix" $C_{\Phi}$ to be the block-matrix
$$
C_{\Phi} = \pmatrix{\Phi(E_{11}) & \cdots & \Phi(E_{1n})\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ \Phi(E_{n1}) & \cdots & \Phi(E_{nn})}.
$$
One may ask the question of when it holds that a map $\Phi$ between spaces of square matrices is such that the matrix $C_{\Phi}$ is positive semidefinite. It turns out that if this matrix is positive definite, then $\Phi$ must be a positive map, but the reverse does not hold. In fact, Choi's theorem states that $C_{\Phi}$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\Phi$ satisfies the stronger condition of *complete positivity*.

---

**Note:** It does not necessarily hold that a positive operator is self-adjoint relative to the standard inner product over $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ given by $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^*)$.  Indeed, as is noted in exercise 2.7.11 of your reference, we find that (taking $n=2$ and $X = E_{12}$) the map $\Phi: A \mapsto a_{22}E_{11}$ has adjoint $\Phi^* : A \mapsto a_{11} E_{22}$.

Here, $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with a $1$ as its $i,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere.

Comment: Is $\Phi$ in that theorem of the type $A\mapsto TA$ as is being asked?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to correct terminology! I googled "positive maps" and found the issue stated more formally (but without proof), updated the question

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov See my latest edit: I've added a definitive example to show that a positive $\Phi$ may fail to be self-adjoint (and therefore fail to be positive definite).