# Is this positive map also completely positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, positive-definite, quantum-mechanics

Can $T$ defined below be shown to be a completely positive map?
$$T(A)=E[(I-XX')A(I-XX')]$$

$T$ maps between covariance matrices, X is a (column)-vector sampled from some $d$-dimensional distribution (ie, multivariate normal), $E$ is expectation over this distribution.

I've verified empirically that the [Choi matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816410/998) is positive for a few empirical distributions of $X$ in 3 dimensions, does this hold more generally?

Comment: What is $E$? $ $

Comment: expectation over $X$ (updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every conditional expectation is CP (completely positive)  by [**1**, IV.3.4],
and every map of the form $A\mapsto B^*AB$ is clearly CP, so your map is a composition of CP maps, hence CP.

[1] *Takesaki, M.*, Theory of operator algebras I., Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 124. Operator Algebras and Non-Commutative Geometry 5. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-42248-X/hbk). xix, 415 p. (2002). [ZBL0990.46034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0990.46034).